# knockoutjs 'Contacts Editor' example sliding animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, knockout.js

In looking at knockoutjs's 'Contacts Editor' example ([link here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html)), the 'Adding a contact' button creates a new section at the bottom. Is there a way to make that expansion at the bttom with the animation effect like jquery's slide down effect?

thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`afterAdd` functionality](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_the__option) of the template binding to do something like what you want.

To do this, you would need to switch the contacts rendering to use the template binding's `foreach` rather than jQuery template's `{{each}}`.

Here is a sample using [1.3 beta's](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/) native template engine: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/am5JD/